# '@' symbol coming in the output json while converting from xml using apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

i am trying to convert xml to json using apache camel , it is working fine. But the out has '@' appended to every attribute.

example : if xml is AAA , i am getting @name:ajay in json .

Below is the code i am using

```
   XmlJsonDataFormat xmlJsonFormat = new XmlJsonDataFormat();
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
   try {
        xmlJsonFormat.setEncoding("UTF-8");

        xmlJsonFormat.setForceTopLevelObject(true);
        xmlJsonFormat.setTrimSpaces(true);
        xmlJsonFormat.setSkipNamespaces(true);
        xmlJsonFormat.setRemoveNamespacePrefixes(true);

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                String ch = "" ; 
     from("file:src/main/resources/input").marshal(xmlJsonFormat).to("file:src/main/resources/output/");

         System.out.println(ch);
            }
        });

        context.start();

        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } finally {
        context.stop();
    }
```

Comment: That is how the xmljson 3rd party library does it by default. You have to research how if possible you can configure this library to not do that. And I think this library is dying/dead and we have deprecated camel-xmljson component also.

Comment: any other way i can convert xml to json then ?

Comment: @HimanshuKhandelwal, you need to think about how to convert this in a proper way. You can use Jackson library to the conversion for you but it all depends on how your json format should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative library, you may use **JSON.org**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>${json.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And implement a `Processor` like this one:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:input")
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                final String xmlBody = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                final String jsonBody = XML.toJSONObject(xmlBody).toString();
                exchange.getIn().setBody(jsonBody);
            }
        })
        .log("************* My body in json format is ${body} *********")
        .to("mock:output");                
}
```

The JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException, CamelExecutionException, IOException {
    getMockEndpoint("mock:output").expectedBodyReceived().body().contains("{\"books\"");
    getMockEndpoint("mock:output").expectedMessageCount(1);


    template.sendBody("direct:input", 
                    IOUtils.toString(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/xml/books.xml"), 
                                    Charset.defaultCharset()));

    getMockEndpoint("mock:output").assertIsSatisfied();
}
```

Given this input:

```
<books>
    <book>
        <title>The Fellowship of the Ring</title>
        <author>J.R.R Tolkien</author>
        <year>1954</year>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>The Two Towers</title>
        <author>J.R.R Tolkien</author>
        <year>1955</year>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>The Return of the King</title>
        <author>J.R.R Tolkien</author>
        <year>1956</year>
    </book>
</books>
```

We have this output:

```
{
"books":{
    "book":[
        {
            "year":1954,
            "author":"J.R.R Tolkien",
            "title":"The Fellowship of the Ring"
        },
        {
            "year":1955,
            "author":"J.R.R Tolkien",
            "title":"The Two Towers"
        },
        {
            "year":1956,
            "author":"J.R.R Tolkien",
            "title":"The Return of the King"
        }
    ]
}
}
```